# let user select roles in the wordpress subsites

Tags: multisite, user-roles

Im stuck this problem for couple of days, Lets check it out..

Site A:Social theme,Role:Subscriber; Site B:Job seeker, Roles:Candidate/Employer; Site C:real estate.Roles:User/agent/agency.and more!

what happen here is when user registered and login to site A will logged to B and C, but B/C couldn't recognize the role and this user not listed in B/C, this user will not able to see the contents at the dashboard, because the dashboard has assigned the page with different contents for different role; For example,at site B, user login as candidate will see the candidate contents at the dashboard; user login as employer will able to post a job etc;

Is there any solutions to let user from site A can select role when passby Site B or Site C, and saved this user to Site B or C.   rather than needing to sign up with same email on site B and more.

Comment: A user in Site A can be added to Site B and Site C, at whatever level is appropriate, by a Super Admin on the system. I don't think it would be wise to allow users to determine their own roles on sites; this seems to me like it would be a *huge* security liability.

Comment: I need the logged user to select Candidate or Employer only when he visit Site B.  and user can select user/agent/agency only when visit Site C. no other roles can be select at front end. otherwise, user will have to sign up site B and C just to select role he want. and couldn‘t use the email address to register， as the email address already listed in network user list.

Comment: The "dashboard" mentioned above is related to user profile, (not main dashboard at the backend) . User not able to see certain profile page as he is not listed or sign up with site B. he couldn't assign candidate or employer because the network allow him to logged in for all sub-sites. What I want is let the logged user to choose to be candidate or employer when he visit Site B.